# Is it possible to set textwidth based on whether the cursor is in code or comments?

Tags: vim, text-width

I'd like to make my comments 80 characters wide while allowing my code to go to 132 characters.

Is there a way to do this? I was looking at synID, but my viml-fu is not up to the task. I'm not even sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [OnSyntaxChange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4085) allows to define hooks based on the syntax under the cursor. This will do what you want:

```
call OnSyntaxChange#Install('Comment', '^Comment$', 0, 'a')
autocmd User SyntaxCommentEnterA setlocal textwidth=80
autocmd User SyntaxCommentLeaveA setlocal textwidth=132
```